# serve files directly from GridFS with reactivemongo

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, reactivemongo

I am using Play Framework 2.2.1 and Scala 2.10. I want to use reactivemongo to directly read files from gridFS so i can open it with a URL in browser e.g. http://www.example.com/playgridfs/filename

How can i achieve that?

Comment: I answered your question in google group here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/reactivemongo/TDTFN23q9vk Feel free to ask any questions!

Comment: I figured out a solution too but i had a look at your solution which is neat and better. Many thanks!      
      val gridFS = new GridFS(db)
      val file = gridFS.find(BSONDocument("filename" -> new BSONString(name)))
      serve(gridFS, file).map(_.withHeaders(CONTENT_DISPOSITION -> "inline;"))